# How do I loop through a CSV file with a batch or PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a CSV file with two different columns, one with PC names and one with MAC addresses like this:

```
PCxxxx 00-11-22-33-44-55
...
...
```

These values should be placed into the following CLI command:

```
wdsutil /Set-Device /Device:PCxxxx /ID:00-11-22-33-44-55
```

Now since there are about 200 of them, I want to automate this.

As a matter of interest, could one do this with batch? It would be quite complicated, right? I thought of arrays, but don't think one can do this in batch.

Maybe with PowerShell it'd be a bit easier.

Comment: Will this help - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/813f3903-83c3-4a6a-9edf-320a341ed99d/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (foo.csv) do (
    wdsutil /Set-Device /Device:%%a /ID:%%b
)
```

Actually, you can do that as a one-liner from `cmd` directly:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %a in (foo.csv) do wdsutil /Set-Device /Device:%a /ID:%b
```

In PowerShell you can use a similar idea:

```
Get-Content foo.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $name,$mac = -split $_
  wdsutil /Set-Device /Device:$name /ID:$mac
}
```

Or use the CSV import cmdlet, but given your question you don't seem to have column headers, so you need to provide them manually:

```
Import-CSV -Delim ' ' -Path foo.csv -Header Name,Mac | ForEach-Object {
    wdsutil /Set-Device "/Device:$($_.Name)" "/ID:$($_.Mac)"
}
```

Comment: The FOR `... delims= "` option is not necessary because the space is the default delimiter. You may use just `for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ...`

Comment: Yes, I just chose to be explicit here. Besides, the default delimiters are spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 3):

```
# First column in csv file must be titled PCName, second column must be titled MacAddress.
Import-Csv myfile.csv | %{ wdsutil /Set-Device /Device:$_.PCName /ID:$_.MacAddress }
```

Warning: not tested.

Comment: The file doesn't appear to have headers so you'd need to provide them manually. Also the default delimiter wouldn't work.